# recommended hostings or web spaces for GIS functionality

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations

I just want to develop a web site which will have a Map and a few layers, including some extra GIS functionality, based on OpenLayers (javascript).

I only know about Amazon EC2 as a candidate for virtual machine in which to install Geoserver or MapServer as spatial server. My client does not want to enable its own server in-house and the maximum budget for server running costs is going to be around 30/35 euros a month.

These are the intended aspects of the project so far:

- Framework: Bootstrap.
- Spatial capabilities: Geoserver + OpenLayers.
- Database: not required.
- Encryption/security: not required.
- Server-side scripting: not required
- Client-side scripting: Javascript only.

Question: From a GIS point of view, which server provider in the market would be my ideal candidate, considering my requirements?

Comment: You've got a number of questions in this Question, and most them are dependent on your customer's opinion and/or wallet.

Comment: I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour] which is designed to introduce all users to the site and its protocols.  In particular it is specific about the need for there to be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is hard to answer (more difficult then those decisions already are) as it is not clear what size your service might be. Did you have any logs evaluated or some other user statistics from former projects?

Spatial servers as you call it are not out there as far as i know, beside the ones you already mentioned like MapBox. When you don´t want to go with Amazon, there are plenty of other root-servers out there where you can get a virtual machine quite cheap. For the beginning when you don´t have many visitors that is enough (for the teachings i´m doing i have the webservices and database on an laptop and it runs for 10-12 simultainious users, so any small server should do). But you have to set up Geoserver on your own, which is not difficult. And as you want to program the client side anyway that shouldn´t be the point.

All cost something, there is nothing really for free. Virtual servers (linux based though) start from less than 10$ a month. But thats, like said in the beginning all up to the amount of usage you expect.

Comment: See my edited question for technical aspects of the project so far